# How to make delay in calling a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to execute a particular number of statements after some delay.
For eg:

```
function findPosX(obj) {
    var curleft = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        while (1) {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            if (!obj.offsetParent) {
                break;
            }
            obj = obj.offsetParent;
        }
    } else if (obj.x) {
        curleft += obj.x;
    }
    return curleft;
}

function findPosY(obj) {
    var curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        while (1) {
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
            if (!obj.offsetParent) {
                break;
            }
            obj = obj.offsetParent;
        }
    } else if (obj.y) {
        curtop += obj.y;
    }
    return curtop;
}
function gotoDiv(index) {
    var ele = document.getElementById("Div" + index);
    var x = findPosX(ele);
    var y = findPosY(ele);
    setTimeout("window.scrollTo(x, y)", 5000);
}
```

Here I want to set the current scroll position to a prticular div. But it's giving me error: **x is undefined**. Let me tell u if I use the functions as below it works fine, so please don't tell me that ele is null and blah blah blah.

```
function gotoDiv(index) {
    var ele = document.getElementById("Div" + index);
    var x = findPosX(ele);
    var y = findPosY(ele);
    window.scrollTo(x, y);
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: ele being null probably won't cause the x being undefined, I think natrium has that solution, but you should check ele for null though ;) i'm sure you've just simplified the code here and you're actually doing it in your code already ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>try</s>

```
setTimeout("window.scrollTo(" + x + ", " + y + ")", 5000);
```

this is not best practice.
Use this in stead:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(x, y); }, 5000);
```

Comment: Do not pass JS code as string to setTimeout function. Please pass a regular javascript function.

Comment: Way to rip bdukes' answer after the fact.

Comment: at least I admit my original answer was not the best one. bdukes is geting more votes so no worries.

Answer (score 14):

You can give `setTimeout` a function, rather than a string, which will let you access those variables:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(x, y); }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the function in a closure and then put the timeout inside the closure.

Comment: already tried that but what if the function requires a paramter?? It's giving the current error bcoz of the same reason..!!